# Reply to a selected or opened mail in outlook using excel macro

Tags: excel, email, outlook, vba

I have made a code in excel which creates a mail using excel envelop. But this code creates a new email, instead, I want to reply to a particular mail which is selected or opened in my outlook. There is no fixed pattern in my emails to which I want to reply such as a particular subject or sender. So I want to reply/replyall to mail only which I select or open in outlook. Where should I make changes in my code? Please Help!!  `

```
'Option Explicit
Private Sub Generate_Ticket_Email_Click()

'varCap = Generate_Ticket_Email.Caption

'Generate_Ticket_Email.Caption = "DiscardMail"

On Error GoTo ErrHandler


'SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
Dim objEmail As Object
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B7:D31").Select

If Generate_Ticket_Email.Caption <> "Generate E-mail" Then
    Generate_Ticket_Email.Caption = "Generate E-mail"
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
    GoTo ErrHandler
End If


 ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
'ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
'End If

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Item.To = Range("J16")
    .Item.CC = Range("J17")
    .Item.Subject = Range("F18")
End With


Generate_Ticket_Email.Caption = "Discard E-mail"

' CLEAR.
Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

ErrHandler:

'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

with

```
Set objEmail = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Reply
```

(error checking omitted)

Comment: Hello Dmitry, The change you suggested didn't change anything in the output. There must be some other changes too. I think there must be some other lines in my code which is creating a new mail instead of a reply.Can you check my code thoroughly please.

Comment: What do you expect to change? Note that your code explicitly overwrites the Subject, To and CC properties that Reply() populates.